# Google script Delete Button not functioning properly

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script

**I am trying to delete the row from google Sheets and I have assigned the script to this button but it not deleting the record when I click the delete button. it gives the message Reacod not found.I have also made a search button which is running properly **

function deleteRow() {

```
var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet

var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("User Form"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet

var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("SUPPORTING SHEET"); ////delcare a variable and set with the Database worksheet

//to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the message box features var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

// Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.

var response = ui.alert("Delete", 'Do you want to delete the record?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

var str = shUserForm.getRange("E13").getValue();

var values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from the used

range and assigning it to values variable

var valuesFound=false; //variable to store boolean value to validate whether values found or not

for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++) { var rowValue = values&[i]; //declaraing a variable and storing the value

//checking the first value of the record is equal to the search item
if (rowValue[0]==str) {

  var  iRow = i+1;
  datasheet.deleteRow(iRow);

  ui.alert("Record Deleted!");

  shUserForm.getRange("E13").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E15").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E17").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E19").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E21").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E23").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E27").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E29").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E31").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E37").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E39").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E41").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E43").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E45").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E49").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E51").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("E53").clear();

  valuesFound=true;

  return;
}
}

if(valuesFound==false)
{
  ui.alert("No RECORD FOUND!");

}
}
```

Comment: This lools suspicious `values&[i]` .  I think it will return 0.  Should it be `values[i]`?

Comment: I have tried this by removing "&" but still not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If `Reacod not found` of `it gives the message Reacod not found.` is `ui.alert("No RECORD FOUND!");` and if the value of `var str = shUserForm.getRange("E13").getValue()` is correct and also the column "A" of "SUPPORTING SHEET" sheet has the value of `str`, I thought that the reason for your issue is due to `var rowValue = values&[i];` as mentioned by [TheWizEd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74101205/google-script-delete-button-not-functioning-properly#comment130833992_74101205). But from `I have tried this by removing "&" but still not working properly`, I'm worried that the column might be different from your expected column.

  - In this case, please check the value of `var str = shUserForm.getRange("E13").getValue()` again.
- By the way, in your script, `ui` is not declared. Please be careful about this.
- In your script, `response` of `var response = ui.alert("Delete", 'Do you want to delete the record?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);` is not used. In this case, the script after this line is run for both "Yes" and "No".
- In your script, I thought that process cost can be reduced a little from your showing script.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function deleteRow() {
  var column = "A"; // Please set the column letter you want to search.

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("User Form");
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("SUPPORTING SHEET");
  var response = ui.alert("Delete", 'Do you want to delete the record?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) return;
  var str = shUserForm.getRange("E13").getValue();
  var ranges = datasheet.getRange(`${column}1:${column}${datasheet.getLastRow()}`).createTextFinder(str).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length == 0) {
    ui.alert("No RECORD FOUND!");
    return
  };
  ranges.reverse().forEach(r => datasheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
  shUserForm.getRangeList(["E13", "E15", "E17", "E19", "E21", "E23", "E27", "E29", "E31", "E37", "E39", "E41", "E43", "E45", "E49", "E51", "E53"]).clear(); // or clearContent()
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ui.alert("Record Deleted!");
}
```

- When this script is run, a search value is retrieved from "E13" of "User Form" sheet. And, using the search value, the rows are searched using TextFinder. In this case, the script can set the search column with `var column = "A";`. When the search value is found, the row is deleted and the ranges `["E13", "E15", "E17", "E19", "E21", "E23", "E27", "E29", "E31", "E37", "E39", "E41", "E43", "E45", "E49", "E51", "E53"]` is cleared.
- If you want to change the search column, please modify `var column = "A";`.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))
- [clear() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clear)

Comment: Thank you soo much Cooper the delete button is working now

Comment: @Mohammad Haroon Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Thank you soo much Cooper the delete button is working now`. If my answer still doesn't resolve your issue, I would like to modify it. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Sorry to address you incorrectely Tanaike.I ma making a form for my clinic and through that form i want to delete, Clear Add records in the sheet but the code for delete button was not working .soo i took help now it working fine

Comment: @Mohammad Haroon Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Sorry to address you incorrectely Tanaike.I ma making a form for my clinic and through that form i want to delete, Clear Add records in the sheet but the code for delete button was not working .soo i took help now it working fine`, I couldn't understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am making a form for my clinic patients in which i am creating some button there which i can add delete select and search my data

Comment: @Mohammad Haroon Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `Thank you for your reply.I am making a form for my clinic patients in which i am creating some button there which i can add delete select and search my data`, I couldn't understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If your issue was still not resolved, I have to apologize and have to modify my answer.

Comment: Yes sir My "Thank you for your reply.I am making a form for my clinic patients in which i am creating some button there which i can add delete select and search my data" My problem have been solved for thedelete button it is working properly and pressing the delete button it is deleting the data

Comment: @Mohammad Haroon Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function deleteRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("User Form");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("SUPPORTING SHEET");
  var response = ui.alert("Delete", 'Do you want to delete the record?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var str = sh1.getRange("E13").getValue();
  var vs2 = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const rgl = sh1.getRangeList(["E13","E15","E17","E19","E21"])l
  var valuesFound = false;
  let d = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < vs2.length; i++) {
    var rowValue = vs2[i];
    if (rowValue[0] == str) {
      var iRow = i + 1;
      sh2.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
      ss.toast("Record Deleted!");
      rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => rg.clearContent());
    }
  }
}
```